# Titanium app won't build in Android after upgrading SDK, resource entry accept is already defined

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-android

After upgrading to Titanium SDK 6.1.0.GA, my app no longer builds. It gives the error:

> [ERROR] Failed to package application: [ERROR]    [ERROR]
>   /Users/justintoth/Documents/housters-mobile/build/android/res/values/strings.xml:51:
>   error: Resource entry accept is already defined. [ERROR]
>   /Users/justintoth/Documents/housters-mobile/build/android/res/values/admob_strings.xml:5:
>   Originally defined here.

Neither strings.xml or admob_strings.xml are files that I myself created or have edited, they are auto-generated. Also, I don't even use admob in my app, Titanium seems to be including it no matter what, which is very wasteful in my opinion.

Here is the full build log:
https://gist.github.com/justintoth/c33f2eb540d6891db99d557bc3f10be7

It works fine on iOS, the issue is only on Android. Any ideas?